# <div> not pushing another <div> down correctly

Tags: html, css

Here is my code to try: http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/DCylg

I have two chat bubbles there. The top one has to push to bottom one down incase there is more chat bubbles that appear, i tried adding a wrapper with a padding-bottom to push the divs but it does nothing.

```
.bubble2{
 float:left 
  
}
.clearfix{display:block; clear:both;}

.bubblewrap {padding-bottom:15%;position:relative;}

.bubble
{
text-align:left;
color:black;
float:left;
position: absolute;
background: gray;   
border-left: 2px solid #e67e22;
margin-left:51px;
padding:5px;
width:500px;
}

.bubble h4 {text-align:left;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;font-variant:small-caps;clear:both;margin-bottom:3px;padding:0;margin-top:-5px;color:#2ecc71;}
.bubble span {font:17px/1px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}

.bubble-img-holder{float:left;}
.bubble-img-holder h4{display:block; float:none; font:12px/12px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
.bubble-img-holder h4 {width:50px;overflow-x:auto}
```

Then my HTML:

```
<div class="bubblewrap">
<div class="holder clearfix"> 
<div class="bubble-img-holder"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/51x50" class="bubble2">
<h4 id=" username2" class="chat-listitem-username" data-bind="text: username">USERddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</h4>
  </div>

<div id="userName" class="bubble" style="display:block; float left;" >
<span class="chat-list item-message" data-bind="html: content">SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM PAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPA<br><br><Br><br><br></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="bubblewrap">
<div class="holder clearfix"> 
<div class="bubble-img-holder"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/51x50" class="bubble2">
<h4 id="username2" class="chat-listitem-username" data-bind="text: username">USERddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</h4>
  </div>

<div id="userName" class="bubble" style="display:block; float left;" >
<span class="chat-list item-message" data-bind="html: content">SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAMSPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM SPAM <br><br><Br><br><br></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the `.bubble` class is absolute. They don't respect document flow. Honestly, I'm not even sure why you're using it.

If you remove it, the divs will start respecting each other's position.

Comment: clearfixes are already in the code. if you remove position absolute it breaks my chat bubble positioning, as it is supposed to be next to the user image...

Comment: So remove the padding/margin then? The `position` property is breaking it, that's all I can tell you. You need to work with that information to fix it.

Comment: http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/DCylg - do you see the chat bubble is now underneath the user image... this is not the positioning of what I want to achieve that's why I used absolute...

Answer (score 0):

solution solved here:http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/DCylg

```
.bubble2{
 float:left 

}
.clearfix{display:block; clear:both;}



.bubble
{border-left: 2px solid #e67e22;
background: gray;   
width:95%;
  left:53px;
  margin-left:52px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom:2%;
}


.bubble-img-holder{float:left;clear:both;display:block;padding:0;margin:0}
.bubble-img-holder h4{display:block; float:none; font:12px/12px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
#username2 {width:50px;overflow-x:auto}
```